# I need a batch file to move pdf files to existing folders

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have about 4000 pdfs that I need to move to existing folders.
Both the pdfs and folders begin with 6 numbers.  I want the batch to recognize the filename by the first 6 numbers and place the pdf in the folder with the same 6 numbers.

The names after the underscore do not have to match only the 6 numbers before the underscore have to match the pdf with the folder.
I want to make a batch file that will move all files/pdfs automatically to the appropriate folders.  I don’t want to create new files only move the pdfs into existing folders.

`Pdf 123456_ABC Company` needs to move to folder `123456_Company ABC`.

Pdfs are in a folder called `DLRDOCS` on my desktop.
The folders the pdfs need to move are in `DLRFLDS` on my desktop.

Comment: Try Bulk Rename Utility: http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Comment: And you have tried ... what?

Comment: Your scenario doesn't match your sample file's name. The first six characters of "Pdf 123456_ABC Company" are "Pdf 12".

Comment: I tried this but nothing happened:     @echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*DLRDOCS.pdf) do (
set z=%%a
set z=!z:~0,6!
if not exist !z! md !z!
  move %%a !z!\

Comment: @echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*DLRDOCS.pdf) do (
set z=%%a
set z=!z:~0,6!
if not exist !z! md !z!
  move %%a !z!\

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "sIn=%userprofile%\desktop\dlrdocs"
set "sOut=%userprofile%\desktop\dlrflds"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%sIn%\*_*.pdf"') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_. " %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
    if not exist "%sIn%\%%~b_%%~d %%~c" md "%sOut%\%%~b_%%~d %%~c"
    move /Y "%sIn%\%%~nxa" "%sOut%\%%~b_%%~d %%~c"
  )
)
exit /b
```

Comment: I tried this and it copied my DLRFLDS to my desktop but did not move any of the pdfs from DLRDOCS to the DLRFLDS.

Comment: Sorry I missed a part of your spec. I fixed it now. The only thing I'm not sure of is if you want the files to be named the same as the new folder. Currently, I'm just moving the file using the original name.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "source=%cd%\dlrdocs"
    set "target=%cd%\dlrflds"

    for %%a in ("%source%\*_*.pdf"
    ) do for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~na"
    ) do for /d %%c in ("%target%\%%b_*"
    ) do if exist "%%~fa" echo move "%%~fa" "%%~fc"
```

To be run from your desktop, if not, adjust source and target folder as needed. It only outputs to console the move commands. If the output is correct, execute again with the `echo` command removed